# Evaluating formula provided by GUI

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, eval

I'm trying to evaluate a simple formula provided via a GUI.
Currently I store the data in a dict with letters as keys (happy to change that, but thought that could come the solution one step closer).
Eventually I want to type in a simple folmula such as "A - J*2"

```
import pandas as pd

data_dict = {}
data_dict['A'] = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
data_dict['C'] = pd.Series([0, 1, 2])
data_dict['E'] = pd.Series([0.5, 1.5, 2.5])
data_dict['J'] = pd.Series([4, 5, 6])

e.g. "A - J*2" ==>
data_dict['A'] - data_dict['J'] * 2
```

The letters will change dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html), but first need create `DataFrame` from `dict` of `Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
print (df)
   A  C    E  J
0  1  0  0.5  4
1  2  1  1.5  5
2  3  2  2.5  6

print (df.eval("A - J*2"))
0   -7
1   -8
2   -9
dtype: int64
```